# How can I call a function for each element of aclass in the main loop?

Tags: python, oop

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z, t, f, g):
        #code
    def function1(self):
        #code    
    def function2(self):
        #code
player1 = Player(1,1,1,1,1,1)
player2 = Player(2,2,2,2,2,2)
...
player100 = Player(1,1,1,1,1,1)

while True:
    player1.function1()
    player1.function2()
    ...
    ...
    player100.function1()
    player100.function2()
    #not efficient!
```

Here there are 100 elements in my class. I want to call function1() and function2() for each element of class in my main loop. I searched by myself but I couldn't find it. What is the efficient way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have so many repeated methods? Seems like to me you are defeating the point of having a method. what is in those functions anyways?

Comment: What is the logic behind the values used to instantiate the object? Why is player 100 `player100 = Player(1,1,1,1,1,1)`?

Comment: @bobveringa Maybe op got tired of copy pasting.

Comment: Make a list of 100 Player objects, instead of making 100 separate variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Create Array of 100 elements

## creating list

list = []

## appending instances to list

```
list.append(Player(1,1,1,1,1,1)) 

list.append( Player(2,2,3,4,5,6) ) 

list.append( Player(1,2,3,4,5,6) ) 

for obj in list:

     obj.function1()

     obj.function2()
```

this code will create list of you Player objects, 3 object and will call the function 1 and 2    3 times

Comment: Thank you very much, I never thought objects can be list elements.